# Special case heading sizes with Foundation 6

Tags: html, sass, zurb-foundation, font-size

TL;DR

What is the best way to add varied font sizing with respect to the built-in breakpoints under Foundation 6?

With Foundation 6 I can adjust the mapping under _settings.scss for the six headings per breakpoint:

```
$header-styles: (
  small: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 39),
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 22),
    'h4': ('font-size': 19),
    'h5': ('font-size': 16),
    'h6': ('font-size': 15),
  ),
  medium: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 39),
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 22),
    'h4': ('font-size': 19),
    'h5': ('font-size': 16),
    'h6': ('font-size': 15),
  ),
);
```

This is okay for top level headings but when I have multiple h1's on a page in the structure markup, I want the h1's in other sub-sections to have a different font size. E.g. 19px instead of the 39px seen above.

```
<header>
  <h1>This is 39px by default. Cool.</h1>
</header>
<article>
  <h1>This should be smaller size in appearance e.g. 19px</h1>
  <p>Both h1's should follow and scale to the breakpoints small, medium, etc.<p>
</article>
```

EDIT:

I've learned that I can add in a class name to the list and it works, but this seems like an improper way to do it and it assumes the secondary h1 will always have the class .special:

```
$header-styles: (
  small: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 39),
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 22),
    'h4': ('font-size': 19),
    'h5': ('font-size': 16),
    'h6': ('font-size': 15),
    '.special': ('font-size': 100),
  ),
  medium: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 39),
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 22),
    'h4': ('font-size': 19),
    'h5': ('font-size': 16),
    'h6': ('font-size': 15),
    '.special': ('font-size': 200),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can specify a location in your HTML (as in your e.g.):

```
$header-styles: (
  small: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 39),
    'article > h1': ('font-size': 100), // target only h1 that are direct children of an article
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 22),
    'h4': ('font-size': 19),
    'h5': ('font-size': 16),
    'h6': ('font-size': 15),
  ),
  medium: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 39),,
    'article > h1': ('font-size': 200), // target only h1 that are direct children of an article
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 22),
    'h4': ('font-size': 19),
    'h5': ('font-size': 16),
    'h6': ('font-size': 15),
  ),
);
```

Depending on your HTML structure you may also be able to use [pseudo selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) like `last-of-type` or `nth-child()` appended to the element type to target more generally. I've always found the specificity approach (above) to be safer than the slightly scatter-gun application from the pseudo selectors.

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I have above, but I feel like that seems slightly dirty, no? The only other option I've found is inside the heading, paragraph, etc. is to add the breakpoint which is tied to Foundation's breakpoint variables under _settings.scss:

    h1 { @include breakpoint(small-up) { // styles } }

Comment: Yep it absolutely does! I'd be worried about unintended consequences and it being overwritten at upgrade time, but other than writing your own SASS / Map and / or variables it seems like the only way.